# Hibernate Persistence cascade = CascadeType.Remove gets constraint Violation error

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I have @oneToMany mapping between User and Property Table with user_id as Foreign Key in Property Table. Now I want that as soon as administrator deletes the User, corresponding Property also to be deleted.

I tried cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE and orphanRemoval=true alone, but I get ConstraintVoilation Exception. After reading other developers advice, Lastly my code is below, Please help me...

User.java :

```
@OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.REFRESH},mappedBy ="user",orphanRemoval=true)
@Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE,
    org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE,
    org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.MERGE,
    org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.PERSIST,
    org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN
    })
private List<Property> properties;
```

Property.java :

```
@Entity
public class Property implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue()
private int id;

private String name;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="user_id")
private User user;
```

The Error while Deleting User is:

```
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:620)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:540)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by:  com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`realestate`.`Property`, CONSTRAINT `FK_77bnqf5go6cydttxwtiig6i9a` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `User` (`userId`))
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
```

I am using Mysql Database and User has Properties mapping.

I will appreciate your help.

Comment: Also let me help with your reputation. I have been in negative repo too.. It really s****

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i almost do the same thing in my program, and it is working fine. Let me show you code

In your User table(Would be better it it is Users, User is already reserved word in most SQLs)

```
@JsonIgnore
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "users", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade =  CascadeType.REMOVE)
private Set<Property> property;
```

And in Property table

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "users")
private Users users;
```

It works fine in my project.

Comment: Hi Kharoud,  Thanks for your response, I tried this but didn't work, maybe now I will change Table Name and Try.